# -RPATH preference not working when executable run with SETUID set

Tags: linux, chmod, rpath

Little bit of background:

I have a execuatable which requires admin-privileges to run. This executable also has a runtime dependency on a custom dynamic lib. That dynamic lib has to be loaded from a custom path (and not from `/usr/lib` because a similar old version of this executable is present on which other libs may be referring to) which the executable is referring to setting up `-RPATH` when compiling the executable.

When I ran that executable from command line using `sudo` command everything works just fine as expected.

Now, this executable is `fork/exec` from another non-root process, for which I am setting up the file permission `chmod` of the executable to `4755`, so that the executable always run as root.

Problem now is the following thing, when I set the file permission `chmod` to `4755`, the `-RPATH` is no longer respected by the system, and my executable defaults to searching for the lib path to `/usr/lib`, over `-RPATH`.

Question: How can I force my executable to prefer `-RPATH` over `/usr/lib`, irrespective of what is there in my file permission (or at least `chmod 4755`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case any soul runs into this issue, here is what I did to resolve this issue.

Simply load the dylibs programmatically by [dlopen APIs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html),  by hardcoding the paths.